# Create a different rectangle with the same size but with a different background color

Tags: javascript, html, css

Explanation:

Every rectangle needs to be shown with a different background color.
I created an array of colors and with the built rand function, active it on the rectangle.
But all rectangles appear in the same color.

```js
    var colors = ['#F44336 ', '#FFEBEE', '#FFCDD2', '#EF9A9A', '#E57373', '#EF5350', '#F44336', '#E53935', '#D32F2F', '#C62828', '#B71C1C', '#FF8A80', '#FF5252', '#FF1744'];
    var counter = 0;
    
    function addRect() {
        var rectobj = document.getElementsByClassName("Rectangles")[0];
        var sections = "";
    
        for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            sections += "<section></section>";
        }
        rectobj.innerHTML = sections;
        
    
        rectobj.style.backgroundColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
    }
    
    addRect();
```

```css
    .Rectangles {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        width: 1000px;
    }
    
    .Rectangles>section {
        height: 350px;
        width: 333px;
    }
```

```html
<main class="Rectangles"></main>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are applying the background color to the `.Rectangles` class.
Try something like this:

```js
var colors = ['#F44336 ', '#FFEBEE', '#FFCDD2', '#EF9A9A', '#E57373', '#EF5350', '#F44336', '#E53935', '#D32F2F', '#C62828', '#B71C1C', '#FF8A80', '#FF5252', '#FF1744'];
var counter = 0;

function addRect() {
    var rectobj = document.getElementsByClassName("Rectangles")[0];
    var sections = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        let bg = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
        sections += "<section style='background:"+bg+"'></section>";
    }
    rectobj.innerHTML = sections;
    

    //rectobj.style.backgroundColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
}

addRect();
```

```css
.Rectangles {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 1000px;
}

.Rectangles>section {
    height: 350px;
    width: 333px;
}
```

```html
        <main class="Rectangles">
        </main>
```

If you need each block to have a different background color you could remove it from the array, but make sure you have enough colors in the array as blocks you will add:

```js
var colors = ['#F44339 ', '#FFEBEE', '#FFCDD2', '#EF9A9A', '#E57373', '#EF5350', '#F44336', '#E53935', '#D32F2F', '#C62828', '#B71C1C', '#FF8A80', '#FF5252', '#FF1744','#bF6734'];
var counter = 0;

function addRect() {
    var rectobj = document.getElementsByClassName("Rectangles")[0];
    var sections = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        let bg = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
        sections += "<section style='background:"+bg+"'></section>";
        let index = colors.indexOf(bg);
        if (index !== -1) {
          colors.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
    rectobj.innerHTML = sections;
    
}

addRect();
```

```css
.Rectangles {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 1000px;
}

.Rectangles>section {
    height: 350px;
    width: 333px;
}
```

```html
  <main class="Rectangles">
        </main>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to change the function to be like that

```
function addRect() {
    var rectobj = document.getElementsByClassName("Rectangles")[0];
    var sections = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        sections += "<section style='background-color: " + colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)] + "'></section>";
    }
    rectobj.innerHTML = sections;
    
}
```

[image]

In your solution, you are assigning them directly to the main container, so, it's always the same